# nginx 502 bad request because of rails query DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I have a page on my application that loads a bunch of data from the database in order to display some images.

I'm receiving a 502 bad gateway from ngnx because all the processing is taking too long, reaching rails time out

this is my code:

```
<% puts @pictures.count %>
  <% @pictures.each do |picture| %>
  <% puts picture.id %>
  <div class="page-header">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <h1 class="title_post" style="color:#015836"><%= picture.title %></h1>
        <p style="font-size:12px; color:#59AA41"><%= picture.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") %></p>
        <p><%= picture.description.truncate(180) %></p>
        <% picture.pictureDatum.each do |image| %>
          <% puts image.id %>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <%= image_tag image.image.url, class: "col-xs-3 col-md-3 img-rounded img-responsive thumbnail" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
        <p class="bnt_ver_mais">
          <%= link_to 'LER MAIS', picture, class:"btn btn-info" %>
          <%= link_to 'DELETE',  { action: :destroy, id: picture.id }, class:"btn btn-danger bnt_voltar_post", method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        </p>
```

the <% picture.pictureDatum.each do |image| %> is taking too long in order to process everything, so rails reach its timeout and return to the client a 502 bad gateway

Ruby should process 14 "rows" with 3 images associated with it, so 42 total.

I want to know how can I process this data without reaching the time out?

**EDIT**

**AFTER RUNNING SOME TESTS**

I executed 
Benchmark.measure { Picture.all.each { |p| p.pictureDatum.all.to_a } }.real

and the total time was only => 5.454484552999929

Now I'm lost! I really don't know what's causing rails to take so long to process this page.

Comment: make your DB faster? faster query? Increase the timeout in nginx?

Comment: Do you know exactly why it takes so long to generate a few links? If yes, fix that. Otherwise find that out first.

Comment: What's the definition of `pictureDatum`? Is that an association? Or a method? If your dataset was large, your problem might be the [N+1 queries problem](http://aspiringwebdev.com/avoid-the-n1-problem-in-rails-by-harnessing-your-database/), but if your data is as small as you say than this shouldn't be a problem. To test that, open up `rails console` and run: `require 'benchmark'; Benchmark.measure { Picture.all.each { |p| p.pictureDatum.all.to_a } }.real`. It should return the number of seconds to iterate over all pictures' pictureDatums.

Comment: Wow! It looks like it takes only 5 seconds... Now I don't know what is making rails take so long to process...